# Block certain screen resolutions from viewing website?

Tags: javascript, html, text, window, resolution

Is it possible to somehow block certain computers from viewing website via screen resolution?

The way I was thinking of doing it would be using `var a = window.screen.height` and `var b = window.screen.width` then doing `<pre id=res></pre>` with `document.getElementById("res").textContent=b+" x "+a;` and now the part I need help with...
How would I make it so that `if res.textContent=1234 x 1234 then allow, but else redirect...` Send help!

-gr3uh

Comment: *"if res.textContent=1234 x 1234"* - It sounds like you're asking about the rendered height and width of a particular element, not of the screen.  If the element must always be that size, why not style it as such?  It's not really clear to me exactly what problem you're trying to solve or why the site can't rely on some responsive styling to solve it.

Comment: "_Is it possible to somehow block certain computers from viewing website via screen resolution?_" - the answer is "NO" - the end user can manipulate what you believe to be "screen resolution".

Comment: Yes the TEXT in that element must equal it.

Comment: @html_java: If that element must always be at least that width and height then you can set that in the CSS with the `min-width` and `min-height` properties.  Overall it would be a good idea to familiarize yourself with responsive design for CSS.  Even just a few CSS media queries can go a long way in styling a website for different screen sizes.  For example, if your application is unsuitable for sizes below a given width then you can style everything to be hidden under that breakpoint and style only a friendly message to show telling the user to use a different device.

Comment: The script prints the current COMPUTERS width and height as <pre>  text, so what I mean is that NOT the <pre> size the COMPUTERS SCREEN size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve my question, Thanks for the feedback anyway, turns out I just needed to make a script like so...

```js
var screenSizeIn = screen.width + " X " +
  screen.height;

console.log("Screen size is: " + screenSizeIn);
if (screenSizeIn == "1280 X 720") { // <-- good screen size
  console.log("Screen size is good!");
} else { // <-- bad screen size
  window.location = "/blocked.html"; // <-- what to do when wrong
  console.log("Screen size is wrong!");
}
```